# What's this error when installing Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, arch-linux

I am trying to install Arch Linux 64 bit on my Windows 8.1 laptop as dual boot with a USB and this line showing never ends.

> udevd[103]: timeout: killing 'usb_id --export
>   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3' [209]

Comment: remove the USB device that's causing it?

Comment: Nothing different, the line showing doesn't end

Comment: I think I can input some commands as I typed pause, it returned sh: pause :not found and continued the error lines